# Android: ListView "setOnItemSelectedListener" not working

Tags: java, android, listview, layout

I have a ListView (of a predefined set of quotes in a string array) in my android program that does not seem to work when an item is selected. The ListView is populated, but the toast message in my onClickListener is never called. I am not sure what the issue is here. I have never run into this problem before.

Here is my onCreate method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        List<String> quotesList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(quotes));
        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, quotesList);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);  
        listView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new ListView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {}
        });
    }
```

Here is my activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#b2cfff"
    tools:context="com.examples.myteststuff.listviews.MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="8dp"
            android:layout_marginVertical="8dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the log file?

Comment: nope. No errors.

Comment: What happens when you set OnItemClickListener?

Comment: I think `setOnItemSelectedListener` works on `spinners `or something, have you tried `setOnItemClickListener` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `setOnItemClickListener` instead :

```
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yep that did it. Thanks.